# Android Calendar Event Update SQLiteException

Tags: android, calendar

I'm having some trouble updating a calendar event. Here's the code I'm using to insert it:

```
long calID = 1;
long startMillis = 0;
long endMillis = 0;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis()+5000;
endMillis = startMillis+1000;
ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, getReminder());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, getNote());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Chicago");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
Log.wtf("EventID", "" + eventID);
```

In my log I get an event ID (10, for example). Then I try updating immediately after:

```
values = new ContentValues();
Uri updateUri = null;
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "TESTING");
updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
int rows = cr.update(updateUri, values, null, null);
Log.wtf("Update", "Rows updated: " + rows);
```

I get an exception on the line `int rows = cr.update(updateUri, values, null, null);`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.innovodynamics.tripplanner, PID: 23267
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:568)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1362)
    at com.innovodynamics.tripplanner.ReminderDialogFragment.writeEvent(ReminderDialogFragment.java:330)
    at com.innovodynamics.tripplanner.ReminderDialogFragment.access$600(ReminderDialogFragment.java:43)
    at com.innovodynamics.tripplanner.ReminderDialogFragment$11.onClick(ReminderDialogFragment.java:294)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: I run your code in my phone, it is ok. So what phone are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I'm running it on the emulator right now but I'll try on a couple actual devices. I was thinking it might be an issue with the calendar not being associated with a Google account.

Comment: Any idea on the reasons behind this exception? I'm having the same problem (it happened on a Samsung s6 device). I forgot to say that this problem happens randomly

Comment: don't forget about this line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko are you sure this will fix the issue ?

Comment: @ShahbazHashmi I don't said that it fix the issue. I just said `don't forget about this line`